# In OpenAPI, how to make some fields of a referenced schema required?

Tags: openapi

I have defined model A which has two fields, `field1` is required.

```yaml
A:
 type: object
 required:
  - field1
 properties:
  field1:
    type: string
  field2:
    type: string
```

I want to create a new schema B, which has the same fields as A, but both fields are required.

Could I write it like this?

```yaml
B:
  allOf:
   - $ref: '#/components/schemas/A'
   - type: object
     required:
     - field2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly how you do this. Note that you don't need to specify `type: object` in schema B because the `type` is already defined in the "parent" schema A.

```yaml
B:
  allOf:
   - $ref: '#/components/schemas/A'
   - required:
     - field2
```

`required` can also be placed alongside `allOf` instead of as a subschema:

```yaml
B:
  allOf:
   - $ref: '#/components/schemas/A'
  required:
   - field2
```

In **OpenAPI 3.1**, `$ref` in schemas allow sibling keywords, so the following will work:

```yaml
B:
  $ref: '#/components/schemas/A'
  required:
   - field2
```